# My bokeh dropdown doesn't cover the whole screen

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using bokeh dropdowns, but the html page doesn't take up the whole screen, rendering the dropdown unusable. Is there a fix for this?

HTML doesn't go down far enough:

[image]

After clicking the dropdown, you can't select options 2 or 3:

[image]

Comment: It is not functional in their [docs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#dropdown-menu) either. And it is an [open issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2549). I'm guessing it is not working correctly anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the `None,` in your menu (line 6), then you will see the list of items.